# Why this error happens: SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c, memory, long-integer, bignum

I have my own long arithmetic set of functions. And I don't know why this error happens because I have only one function which is change the value of __INTINF var and when I increase the value I call another functions which is do: (if we close to overflow just realloc x2size).

Error:

```
==11157==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60e0004b72c0 at pc 0x55bf1bedcc01 bp 0x7ffc5d6d6c00 sp 0x7ffc5d6d6bf0
READ of size 8 at 0x60e0004b72c0 thread T0
    #0 0x55bf1bedcc00 in inf_sum /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:72
    #1 0x55bf1bedcedc in inf_add /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:91
    #2 0x55bf1bedd037 in inf_product /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:106
    #3 0x55bf1bedd19e in inf_multi /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:115
    #4 0x55bf1bedd2c5 in inf_pow /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:127
    #5 0x55bf1bedc448 in main /home/user/C/longArithmetic/test.c:14
    #6 0x7f8425afed8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #7 0x7f8425afee3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #8 0x55bf1bedc264 in _start (/home/user/C/longArithmetic/test.out+0x1264)

0x60e0004b72c0 is located 0 bytes to the right of 160-byte region [0x60e0004b7220,0x60e0004b72c0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f8425e99887 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x55bf1bedc574 in inf /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:16
    #2 0x55bf1bedd132 in inf_multi /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:113
    #3 0x55bf1bedd2c5 in inf_pow /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:127
    #4 0x55bf1bedc448 in main /home/user/C/longArithmetic/test.c:14
    #5 0x7f8425afed8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /home/user/C/longArithmetic/intinf.c:72 in inf_sum
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c1c8008ee00: fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd
  0x0c1c8008ee10: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c1c8008ee20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c1c8008ee30: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa
  0x0c1c8008ee40: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c1c8008ee50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c1c8008ee60: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c1c8008ee70: fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c1c8008ee80: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c1c8008ee90: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c1c8008eea0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==11157==ABORTING
```

This is important definitions.

```
#define MODULO      (1000000000000000000ULL)
#define START_SIZE  (20)

typedef long long          int64;
typedef unsigned long long u64;
typedef unsigned char      u8;
```

This is src code of functions.

```
void inf_sum(__INTINF *dst, __INTINF *num1, __INTINF *num2)
{
    __inf_clear(dst);

    __INTINF *max_num = NULL;
    int64     max_count = 0;
    u8        carry_flag = 0;
    if (num1->count > num2->count) {
        max_num = num1;
        memset(num2->digits + num2->count, 0, num1->count - num2->count);
    }
    else if (num2->count > num1->count) {
        max_num = num2;
        memset(num1->digits + num1->count, 0, num2->count - num1->count);
    } else {
        max_num = num1;
    }
    max_count = max_num->count;

    for (int i = 0; i < max_count; ++i) {
        dst->count++;
        __inf_domain_expansion(dst);
        dst->digits[i] = num1->digits[i] + num2->digits[i] + carry_flag;
        carry_flag = 0;
        if (dst->digits[i] > MODULO - 1) {
            dst->digits[i] -= MODULO;
            carry_flag = 1;
        }
    }
    
    if (carry_flag) {
        dst->count++;
        __inf_domain_expansion(dst);
        dst->digits[dst->count] = carry_flag;
    }
}

void inf_add(__INTINF **num1, __INTINF *num2)
{
    __INTINF *new_num1 = inf();

    inf_sum(new_num1, *num1, num2);

    inf_free(*num1);

    *num1 = new_num1;
}

void inf_product(__INTINF **dst, __INTINF *num1, __INTINF *num2)
{
    __inf_clear(*dst);

    int64 times = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num2->count; ++i) {
        times = (num2->digits[i]) * (int64)pow(MODULO, i);;
        for (int j = 0; j < times; ++j) {
            inf_add(dst, num1);
        }
    }
}

void inf_multi(__INTINF **num1, __INTINF *num2)
{
    __INTINF *new_num1 = inf();

    inf_product(&new_num1, *num1, num2);

    inf_free(*num1);

    *num1 = new_num1;
}

void inf_pow(__INTINF **dst, __INTINF *num, u64 exp)
{
    __inf_copy(dst, num);

    for (int i = 0; i < exp - 1; ++i) {
        inf_multi(dst, num);
    }
}

static void __inf_domain_expansion(__INTINF *num)
{
    if (num->count >= num->size) {
        num->size *= 2;
        num->digits = (u64*)realloc(num->digits, num->size * sizeof(u64));
        memset(num->digits + num->count, 0, num->size);
    }
}
```

This is main file.

```
    __INTINF *n1 = inf(); /* Allocate memmory to var n1 */
    __INTINF *n2 = inf(); /* Allocate memmory to var n1 */

    inf_put(n1, 127ULL); /* Initializes n1 data */

    inf_pow(&n2, n1, 6512); /* Raises n1 to power of 6512 */
```

I tried change the condition in `static void __inf_domain_expansion(__INTINF *num)` functions, like `if ((float)(num->count) / (float)(num->size) * 100 > EXPAND_AT)`, EXPAND_AT equals to 80. Also I tried to debbug this code a lot of times. And what I found out problem is I don't have enough allocated memory in digits array.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve]. You could also run the code in a debugger and see what is going on or add some printf debugging to keep track of what you've allocated and what is being accessed to see if they match up.

Comment: In order to be *reproducible*, the code needs to be able to compile and run.  The first problem here is that you have left out the `intinf.h` and `intinf_static.h`.  It's also not very *minimal*; try to remove or stub out any code that isn't needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think post ready to read now @NateEldredge

Comment: The definition of `__INTINF` is still missing.  And please put all those snippets into a single code block.  Then make sure that you can paste the exact contents of that code block into an empty file, and that it will compile, run, and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Besides the memory management, the algorithm of `inf_product` is fundamentally flawed.   `(int64)pow(MODULO, i)` will overflow for any `i > 1` (and will give the wrong answer even when `i == 1`, because `pow` has inputs and outputs in `double` which can't exactly represent the number 1000000000000000000.  And even if you could get that loop to iterate correctly, it would take a minimum of several decades for any multiplier larger than one "digit".  You really need a real multiplication algorithm - repeated addition is not viable.